# Cross check two tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have two table in my database, one contain attendance of employees while the other contains payroll of employees. inorder for an employee to get paid his name should exist on both table, my question is how to write the program that looks in the two table using id of an employee and list names that found ......am working with php and mysql

attendance table

```
id   name        
1    mark

2    jhon
```

payroll table

```
id     name      salary
1      mark      20000$
2      jhon      3999$
```

Comment: Maybe take a look at a `MySQL JOIN`

Comment: mark having good income `20000$` :) explore JOINS, u do not have any relation in both tables i think.

Comment: You need to use MySQL INNER JOIN on two tables as you need employees having rows is both the tables.

Comment: Suggestion - you should use `emp_id` in payroll table instead of name. Then use join 
`select a.name 
      from attendance a
      join payroll p 
      on a.id = p.emp_id;`

Comment: Tnx it helps alot

Comment: @henockwakshuma When you found a solution, it would be nice that you mark the question as solved, by clicking on the check mark in the answer section below (the checkmark left to the question, that is your solution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use an JOIN. In this case a INNER JOIN should do the trick. But there are also other kind of joins.

[image: Inner join]

Select all records from Table A and Table B, where the join condition is met.

[image: Left join]

Select all records from Table A, along with records from Table B for which the join condition is met (if at all).

[image: Right join]

Select all records from Table B, along with records from Table A for which the join condition is met (if at all).

[image: Full join]

Select all records from Table A and Table B, regardless of whether the join condition is met or not.

In this case you can use the `INNER JOIN` like this

```
SELECT attendance.name, payroll.salary FROM attendance INNER JOIN payroll ON attendance.name = payroll.name
```

This will select the name and the salary if they exist.

Maybe you should change the key names to the ones in your database

> For the record, got the images from http://www.sql-join.com/sql-join-types

Answer (score 1):

You can use join query to fetch data from those tables.
If you do not know how to use it then take a look at the following link
[SQL Join tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Comment: it will work, if IDs of both tables having some relation.

Comment: set the id in payroll table as a foreign key. Where you can define payroll.id references attendance.id